# spark filter on external variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a series of sales records which are in an RDD like so,

```
case class salesRecord(startDate: Int, startTime: Int, itemNumber: Int)

val transactions: RDD[salesRecords]
```

each day is separated by a startDate and startTime which are the seconds since midnight.  I need to be able to filter the start time between two bands which have been input by the user.

so imagine the user has input

```
val timeBandStart: Int  //example 100
val timeBandEnd: Int // 5000
```

and they only want the records of each day between these bands, so to do this I've tried the following.

```
val timeFiltered = transactions.filter { record =>

    record.startTime >= timeBandStart && record.startTime <= timeBandEnd
}
```

the issue i'm facing is that I get nothing on my output, I know for sure the records are within these time bands, so should appear on my output. To try and debug this I've tried extract what the timebands which i'm trying to filter on, with this.

```
val test = transactions.map( (record.startTime, timeBandStart, timeBandEnd)
```

My output of this is the following (32342, 0, 0), (32455, 0, 0).

Why are my timeBands not being set within the filter? I thought this could be something to with the variables not being broadcast to all of the nodes, so I tried placing the timebands with a broadcast variable. But that didn't work....

Probably something really stupid, can somebody point out what i'm doing wrong?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my bug, it's related to this issue. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4170

I'm now not extending from App and instead using the main method. My filter is now being applied correctly.

Thanks for your help!